# How can I return a string from a call to ffi:c-inline in ecl?

Tags: c, common-lisp, ecl

How can I return a string constant from a call to `ffi:c-inline`?

I've tried variations of the following without success (`ORGANIZATION` is a constant defined in constants.h):

```
(ffi:clines "#include \"./constants.h\"")
(ffi:c-inline () () :string "ORGANIZATION" :one-liner t)
```

The example above results in the following compiler error:

> Unknown representation type :STRING

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:cstring` instead of `:string`:

constants.h:

```
#define ORGANIZATION "foobar"
```

ecl.lsp:

```
(ffi:clines "#include \"./constants.h\"")
(defun myfun ()
  (ffi:c-inline () () :cstring "ORGANIZATION" :one-liner t))
```

From ecl prompt:

```
> (compile-file "ecl.lsp" :load t)
...
> (myfun)

"foobar"
>
```

Reference: https://ecl.common-lisp.dev/static/manual/Foreign-Function-Interface.html#Primitive-Types

Comment: Also, are you aware of any documentation which enumerates all of the available types? I've searched both before/after receiving your answer and haven't found anything relevant.

Comment: They are listed here: https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/static/ecldoc/Extensions.html#Primitive-Types